# Only hAC is available after setting up system with a standard recipe

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

After executing the below commands using one of the recipes available in the standard hybris 6.4 package, only hAC is accessible, but the frontend, backoffice and hMC are not. If I try to open, e.g., the backoffice, it gets me to hAC.

These are the commands:

```
install.bat -r <recipe> initialize
install.bat -r <recipe> start
```

What do I miss to make the above components available?

Comment: i think there is a bug that basically requires you to do the setup with a recipe in two steps.. you first just invoke e.g. `install.bat -r b2c_acc` and then to the initialize `install.bat -r b2c_acc initialize` .. (and then do the `start` if you do that through the recipe commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide some more information about - generated localextensions.xml. Also, can you check if the workspace contains models (signifying the *ant clean all* was completed successfully)

Also, please go to HAC->Platform->Extensions and see if the backoffice, storefront are deployed.

Sometimes, the installation recipe does not functions correctly due to which some installation steps are skipped. You are advised to do *ant clean initialize* and check again.

Please let me know if you still face issues.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much Vikrant. Yes, the _ant clean all_ was completed successfully. I will check the localextensions.xml and follow your suggestions and revert.

Comment: After enabling all required extensions in the localextensions.xml file I got all cockpits and the frontend, however there is no sample data, initialization and update didn't help, so there are some other steps missing in installing the recipe. But the answer addresses the question, so marking it as a correct answer.